# New apache2 virtual host only works for new visitors or incognito windows

Tags: virtualhost, apache2

I'm managing a LAMP stack and have tried to get a subdomain to redirect to an external url. We are running Apache 2.2.22 (Debian).

I have created a simple virtual host to redirect to the external url:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName sub.mydomain.tld
  RedirectPermanent / https://outgoing.url/
</VirtualHost>
```

After enabling the virtual host and reloading apache2 the subdomain works correctly for browsers that haven't visited the main site before and incognito windows, but if I have visited the main site before it will redirect to the main site.

I'm guessing it is a caching problem, but I can't figure out how to fix it so that visitors that have visited the main site before can visit the subdomain without clearing their cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ctrl+F5 ?
Clients need clear cache. By default, cache keeps data 1-3 hours.

Comment: Ctrl+F5 and clearing cookies and data from the specific site did not work, but clearing files+image cache from all sites did work.  

I guess I'll just have to wait a while before it'll be visible for everyone, thanks!

Comment: Just for future reference: When you change the target of your domain name this won't help, you will just have to wait until the DNS-Servers between the clients and the site have refreshed their caches, I once had a worst case scenario with an ISPs DNS having a 24h cache. And I kept thinking I misconfigured something.